# Existence and Uniqueness of Geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm reading the theorem 4.10 of the book "Riemannian manifolds" by John Lee. In proof, page 58, the author refers to the existence and uniqueness theorem for first-order ODEs [Boo86, Theorem IV.4.1]. Also in page 60, theorem 4.12 is about the Existence and Uniqueness for Linear ODEs. I want to know if this two theorem are the same? Is there any difference between them? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The existence and uniqueness theorem for first-order ODE's is an important theorem that is discussed in many sources (although I don't have the book Lee refers to in front of me). A loose statement of the theorem is:

A reasonable system of ODE's with specified initial conditions of the form $$y'(t) = f(t, y(t)), ~ y(0) = y_0$$
has a unique solution for at least a short time, i.e., for $t$ in some neighborhood of $0$.
("Reasonable" means that $f$ can be Lipschitz, for example.)

The standard proof uses Picard iteration and the contraction mapping theorem (a.k.a. the Banach fixed point theorem). See the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem

Some comments:

1. This theorem applies to *nonlinear* ODE systems, i.e., $f$ is allowed to depend nonlinearly on $y(t)$. (Note, though, that the equation is linear in $y'(t)$.)
2. This theorem is about *first*-order ODE systems, but an ODE system of any order can be rephrased as a first-order system by introducing new variables if necessary. (It needs to be linear in the highest-order derivatives for the theorem to apply, though.)

Regarding the geodesic equation: the geodesic equation is a second-order nonlinear system to which this theorem applies, so given an initial condition, the geodesic equation has a unique solution for at least short time (this is Lee's Theorem 4.10). In the proof of Theorem 4.10, Lee makes explicit the rephrasing of the second-order system as a first-order system by introducing new variables.

Regarding Lee's Theorem 4.12: the assumptions are stronger than in the above general existence and uniqueness theorem because the system is now *linear*. The linearity means that a stronger result holds: rather than just short-time existence, solutions exist for all $t$. Lee uses this to prove Theorem 4.11 about parallel translation along curves. The parallel translation equation is linear, but the geodesic equation is not.